# Path to Cordova after NPM install

Tags: node.js, windows, cordova, npm, windows-10

I ran

```
npm install -g cordova
```

now what? Where is the `cordova.cmd`? Where is the content, this command downloaded?

I have sought `C:\Program Files\Nodejs` and found nothing.

Comment: if you install with -g it's global, so you can use `cordova` command anywhere, you shouldn't worry about where it is

Comment: Run [`npm root -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root) to see the path to where globally installed libraries are downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the installation path after you call `npm install -g`.
I just ran the command in my Windows machine and I have it under: `C:\Program Files\npm\node_modules\cordova`.

You can now start `cordova` from anywhere on cmd. Try `cordova --help`.